# Detecting palm lines with OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm studying OpenCV with python by working on a project which aims to detect the palm lines.

[image]

What I have done is basically use *Canny edge detection* and then apply *Hough line detection* on the edges but the outcome is not so good.

[image]

Here is the source code I am using:

```
original = cv2.imread(file)
img = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
save_image_file(img, "gray")

img = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
save_image_file(img, "equalize")

img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (9, 9), 0)
save_image_file(img, "blur")

img = cv2.Canny(img, 40, 80)
save_image_file(img, "canny")

lined = np.copy(original) * 0
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(img, 1, np.pi / 180, 15, np.array([]), 50, 20)
for line in lines:
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
        cv2.line(lined, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255))
save_image_file(lined, "lined")

output = cv2.addWeighted(original, 0.8, lined, 1, 0)
save_image_file(output, "output")
```

I tried different parameter sets of Gaussian kernel size and Canny low/high thresholds, but the outcome is either having too much noises, or missing (part of) major lines. Above picture is already the best I get, so far..

Is there anything I should do to get result improved, or any other approach would get better result?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm very interested in this subject, I'm just starting R&D on it; have you progressed since? Can we discuss it in private? Thanks!

Comment: @Doubidou, sorry, I don't have any further progress from what I posted above.

Comment: have you tried taking a look at state of the art papers on this? I was interested in the subject back in 2012 but there weren't many papers that I could use. I ended up adapting software from NASA which tracks land crests and rivers.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is really experimental. You have already done the most important function. I suggest that you tune your parameters to get a reasonable and a noisy number of lines, then you can make some filtering:

- using morphological filters,
- classification of lines
  (according to their lengths, fits on contrasted area...etc)
- improving your categories by dividing the area of palm (without
  fingers) into a grid (4x4 .. where 4 vertical fingers corners can
  define the configs of the grid).
- calculate the gradient image,
  orientation of lines may help as well
- Make a search about the algorithm "cumulative level lines detection", it can help for the certainty of detected lines